# binding form with Spring Webflow

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, binding

i have a problem with Spring and forms in JSPs... i need to bind an object with a form in order to upload a file and work with it.

i have read a lot of post but most of them use Spring MVC and controllers to do that. in this case i don't know how to do it holding the flow.
the next code doesn't work:

Bean:

```
public class RDTesterBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4271292669198998728L;

String tipoLanzador;

private  MultipartFile excelFile;

ContenedorGovernor contenedorGovernor;



public String getTipoLanzador() {
    return tipoLanzador;

}

public void setTipoLanzador(String tipoLanzador) {
    this.tipoLanzador = tipoLanzador;
}



public MultipartFile getExcelFile() {
    return excelFile;
}
public void setExcelFile(MultipartFile excelFile) {
    this.excelFile = excelFile;
}
public ContenedorGovernor getContenedorGovernor() {
    return contenedorGovernor;
}

public void setContenedorGovernor(ContenedorGovernor contenedorGovernor) {
    this.contenedorGovernor = contenedorGovernor;
}
```

JSP with form:

```
<form:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="${flowExecutionUrl}" modelAttribute="RDTesterBean">
        <div id="form_excel">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="hidden" id="tipoLanzador" path="tipoLanzador"
                    name="idtipoLanzador" >

                <legend>
                    <span id="leyendForms"><%=MessageUtils.getMessage("excelFileName") %></span>
                </legend>
                <input type="file" path="excelFile" id="excelFile" name="excelFile"
                    >
```

flow.xml

```
<view-state id="mainView" view="mainView" model="RDTesterBean">
    <var name="RDTesterBean" class="main.java.beans.RDTesterBean" />
    <transition on="loadExcelLanzador" to="mainView">
        <evaluate
            expression="RDTesterManagerService.loadExcelLanzador(RDTesterBean,flowRequestContext)" />
    </transition>
```

Service.java

```
public class RDTesterManagerService {


public String loadExcelLanzador(RDTesterBean RDBean, RequestContext rc) {
```

...
...
Here RDBean.getExcelFile() return null
how can i get this multipartFile?

thanks! :D

Comment: Which version of Spring Webflow do you use?

Comment: Spring Webflow Version 2.3.0

Comment: don't know about 2.3.0; in version 1 (don't know if this has changed) you do something like MultipartFile document = context.getRequestParameters().getRequiredMultipartFile(fileName); (the interface ParameterMap has also another method getMultipartFile(String parameterName))